# Как зациклить анимацию (setInterval)

Tags: javascript, анимация

Пишу себе велосипед, кубик должен бесконечно двигаться вправо и возвращаться.
Происходит только 1 итерация.Если добавить в left_go() в else if{ setInterval(right_go, 5);} , все работает, но со временем анимация начинает тормозить и зависать.
Помогите пожалуйста?

```
var animate_right = setInterval(right_go, 5);

function right_go () {
    var left_padding = cube_style.left;
    if (left_padding!=width_square){
        cube.style.left = x +"px";
        x++;
        console.log(left_padding);
    }
    else if(left_padding=width_square){
        clearInterval(animate_right);
        var animate_left = setInterval(left_go, 5);
    }
}

function left_go (animate_left) {
    var left_padding = cube_style.left;
    if (left_padding!='-1px'){
        cube.style.left = x +"px";
        x--;
        console.log(left_padding);
    }
    else if(left_padding!=width_square){
        clearInterval(animate_left);
    }
}
```

Comment: по опыту скажу, что лучше не `setInterval` использовать,  а рекурсивный `setTimeout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oбе переменные, `animate_left` и `animate_right`, должны быть глобальными, а у Вас `clearInterval(animate_left);` ничего не делает, так как переменная `animate_left` в этом месте не определена. Соответственно, таймеры с `left_go` через каждые 5 миллисекунд накапливаются, и все тормозит.

Код должен быть симметричен относительно `left` и `right`.

```
var animate_right = setInterval(right_go, 5);
var animate_left = null;

function right_go () {
    var left_padding = cube_style.left;
    if (left_padding!=width_square){
        cube.style.left = x +"px";
        x++;
        console.log(left_padding);
    }
    else if(left_padding=width_square){
        clearInterval(animate_right);
        animate_left = setInterval(left_go, 5); // !!! no var
    }
}
```

Comment: переменные `animate_left`  и `animate_right` следует определять как setInterval или как то по-другому? Если определить их через setInterval они оба запускаются и начинают конфликтовать друг с другом и кубик на месте дергается.

Comment: Спасибо большое все заработало!